# Drupal: No access after DB password change

Tags: mysql, drupal, passwords

I changed the password of my mysql database for my drupal cms via the form of my hoster. Then I gave write access to the "sites/deafault"-Folder and changed the password in the settings.php.

But I get the message Site off-line on http://asv-arnbach.de/ ...
I changed the password back and changed it back in the settings.php - did not help anyway.

How can I get my site back running?

Best regards
Markus

Comment: Seems like database connection settings in your settings.php are not correct. Make sure that they are correct.

Comment: Fastest way is to change the associate database user password again from the host/cPanel and correct the details in the settings.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the two hints, I checked my settings.php
I set a new password in my host/c Panel and in the settings.php and everything worked. Maybe some copy/paste problem.

Thanks for your advice.